# Creating new column in database based upon user input/content in previous column

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm making a database that takes user input and storing it in the database. However I want each row in the database (db) to be unique to each user and to contain separate input (thats the users put in)

This is the code I have so far:

```
 user_id = random_number_genned_here
 keyword = input_from_user  
 sqlite_file = 'keywords.sqlite' 
 conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
 c = conn.cursor() 
 c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyword(userid TEXT UNIQUE, keyword TEXT)""")
 try:
      c.execute("""INSERT INTO keyword (userid , keyword) VALUES (?, ?, )""", (user_id,ukeyword))
 except:
      #where I need help
```

So basically what I need to do 2 things.

First thing: I need to see if a userid is already in the databse. The try and except does that. If it isn't in the database then I need to create a row in the database for that userid and add the keyword into the keyword column. 
If a userid is already in the database then I need to add the keyword to the column.

Second thing: If the keyword column has some text in it, then I need to column to store the new keyword in.

I have bit and pieces of it but I don't know how to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

To add a column to a table you can use the ALTER TABLE SQL

```
ALTER TABLE keyword ADD COLUMN your_column_definition
```

[SQL As Understood By SQLite ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

You would have to generate the SQL programatically.

However, it would be simpler to look at the design of the keyword table. Why have the userid as UNIQUE when there are multiple data items to be stored per userid? I'd suggest that matters would be simplified if you were to have a composite UNIQUEness that is make userid and keyword combined as UNIQUE.

e.g. perhaps use :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyword(userid TEXT, keyword TEXT, UNIQUE(userid,keyword));
```

Perhaps consider the following demo :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS keyword;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyword(userid TEXT, keyword TEXT, UNIQUE(userid,keyword));
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO keyword VALUES
    ('User001','TEST'),('User001','NOT A TEST'),('User001','KEYWORD A'),('User001','TEST'),
    ('User002','TEST'),('User002','KEYWORD A'),('User002','KEYWORD B')
;
    -- Ooops (not really as duplicates just get ignored)
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO keyword VALUES
    ('User001','TEST'),('User001','NOT A TEST'),('User001','KEYWORD A'),('User001','TEST'),
    ('User002','TEST'),('User002','KEYWORD A'),('User002','KEYWORD B')
;
SELECT * FROM keyword;
SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE userid = 'User001';
```

When run the message log shows :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS keyword
> OK
> Time: 0.439s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyword(userid TEXT, keyword TEXT, UNIQUE(userid,keyword))
> OK
> Time: 0.108s


INSERT OR IGNORE INTO keyword VALUES
    ('User001','TEST'),('User001','NOT A TEST'),('User001','KEYWORD A'),('User001','TEST'),
    ('User002','TEST'),('User002','KEYWORD A'),('User002','KEYWORD B')
> Affected rows: 6
> Time: 0.095s


-- Ooops (not really as duplicates just get ignored)
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO keyword VALUES
    ('User001','TEST'),('User001','NOT A TEST'),('User001','KEYWORD A'),('User001','TEST'),
    ('User002','TEST'),('User002','KEYWORD A'),('User002','KEYWORD B')
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s


SELECT * FROM keyword
> OK
> Time: 0s


SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE userid = 'User001'
> OK
> Time: 0s
```

- Note that the second insert inserts 0 rows as they are all duplicates

The queries produce :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you set your_column_definition to a random number?

Comment: your_column_definition is the the entire statement for defining the column, it could not just be a number, some parts could contain a random number depending upon the rule for the various parts such a number would have to be generated progamatically but I'd suggest you would then be making life quite difficult for yourself. e.g how are you then going to access such a column?

Comment: True didn't think about that. I think I found a new way to do this, I'll post once I test it